# can a pass in passbook have no bar code?

Tags: ios6, passbook

I want to display bar code but only a coupon in my pass.
Can it work?

such as remove this code in pass.json:
    `"barcode" : {

        "message" : "All you need is love",

        "format" : "PKBarcodeFormatPDF417",

        "messageEncoding" : "iso-8859-1"

    }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove barcode from Pasbook' Pass just remove the whole barcode section from the pass.json and rebuild the pass.

Comment: Worth noting that the reason some sources (e.g., the excellent tutorial on Wenderlich's site) act as though the barcode is required is because it *used* to be.  It no longer is in 6.0.1, so you can safely ignore sources that say otherwise.